# Independent scroll for display:table-cell divs

Tags: html, css

Given this 3 columns layout,

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">uno</div>
  <div class="center">dos</div>
  <div class="right">tres</div>
</div>
```

How do I make these 3 columns (being display:table-cell) scroll independently one from each other.

Comment: _**scroll independently one from each other**_ what is this mean?

Comment: Scroll which way?

Comment: overflow is only supported on block level containers not table cells. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make each div scroll-able separately

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper>div {
      display: table-cell;
    }

.left, .center, .right {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">uno</div>
      <div class="center">dos</div>
      <div class="right">tres</div>
    </div>
```